# код не работает,в чем ошибка?Выдает пустоту

Tags: c, файлы, файловый-ввод-вывод

это таблица умножения

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
     FILE *file = fopen("file.txt","w");
     int a = atoi(argv[1]);
     int b = atoi(argv[2]);
     int i,j,c;
     for(i = 1; i < a; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j < b; j++){
           c = i * j;
           fprintf(file, "%4d", c );
        }
     putchar('\n');
     }
     fclose(file);
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: А что вы передаете программе в качестве параметров командной строки?

Comment: а если на экран вывести, то что выдает или в отладчике пройтись

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если чуть подправить -

```
       c = i * j;
       fprintf(file, "%4d", c );
    }
    fprintf(file,"\n");  // << -- вот тут подправить
 }
```

и **передать в командной строке правильные аргументы** - например, я передал `5  5` - то получается нормальный файл:

```
 1   2   3   4
 2   4   6   8
 3   6   9  12
 4   8  12  16
```

Мне кажется, ваша главная проблема - что вы не передали ничего в командной строке... Давайте честно - код ваш или нашли в интернете, а он не работает? :)

Comment: я студент,занимаюсь по книге.Тут есть примеры и я по ним ориентировался

Comment: Ну, значит, ориентация оказалась неверной. Передавайте значения в командной строке - и код заработает.

Comment: Спасибо большое!!